# Angularjs filters - subsequent filters not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page that has data filtered on a numerous amount of values.
for each list block i use

```
data-ng-repeat="c in vm.competencies | filter : c.competencyTypeID = <number>"
```

some of the filters work, then the remaining will not return the correct items.

I use the same array on all, which contains the correct number of items.

There are twenty ids being filtered on the same page.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Correct syntax is      filter: {competencyTypeID: <number>}

Comment: Jbrown's answer is correct, however, its worth mentioning that in DOM angular filters have some pretty intense performance implication. I'd carefully consider before making the decision to use them.

Further reading: https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/

Comment: thanks, i'll look into that.. i didnt get to design the database...which is really the underlying cause of using filters...

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use filters directly in the DOM with pipe `|`. Because it has performance issue as it runs in every `$digest` cycle. Make a filter `service` and in that create a filter function. Call that function from the `controller` to filter `competencies`. Then use ng-repeat directly on `competencies`.